# Is there RCF docs for PDF?

Tags: go, pdf

My goal is to create a `PDF to CSV`. In this case, converting journal entries from the PDF file into CSV file.

What I've tried:

1. use `pdftotext` from linux.

   The Installation:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
   ```

   The code:

   ```
   package main

   import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
   )

   func main() {
    body, err := exec.Command("pdftotext", "-layout", "-q", "-nopgbrk", "-enc", "UTF-8", "-eol", "unix", "/Volumes/T7Touch/Learn/e-statement-to-t-account/5725299769Jul2022.pdf", "-").Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
   }
   ```

   **Does it work?**
   The `-layout` option makes the output workable. The `fmt.Println(string(output))` will print every journal entry per line.

   ```
   row1column1 row1column2 row1column3
   row2column1 row2column2 row2column2
   ```

   Without the `-layout` option, the output will be not readable.

   ```
   row1column1
   row2column1
   row1column2
   row2column2
   ```

   The problem is that this solution need to install `poppler-utils` to use `pdftotext`. Without it, it will throws error.

   ```
   $ GOOS=darwin GOARCH=arm64 go build
   $ ./main // will throw errors -> panic: exec: "pdftotext": executable file not found in $PATH
   ```
2. use `https://github.com/ledongthuc/pdf`
   The code

   ```
   package main

   import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/ledongthuc/pdf"
   )

   func main() {
    content, err := readPdf(os.Args[1]) // Read local pdf file
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(content)
    return
   }

   func readPdf(path string) (string, error) {
    f, r, err := pdf.Open(path)
    defer func() {
        _ = f.Close()
    }()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    totalPage := r.NumPage()

    for pageIndex := 1; pageIndex <= totalPage; pageIndex++ {
        p := r.Page(pageIndex)
        if p.V.IsNull() {
            continue
        }

        rows, _ := p.GetTextByRow()
        for _, row := range rows {
            println(">>>> row: ", row.Position)
            for _, word := range row.Content {
                fmt.Println(word.S)
            }
        }
    }
    return "", nil
   }
   ```

I intend to create pdf decoder that does exactly like `$ pdftotext -layout` without the need to do `$ sudo apt-get install popper-utils`. **I believe that I can solve this if someone can help point out where to see `pdftotext` repository or RFC docs for PDF.**

Comment: You can retrieve the "older free Adobe version" at https://www.adobe.com/go/pdfreference/

Comment: @KJ I am not sure about `pdfcpu.io`. But I think, it does not provide function to be called, am I right? In other words, I can't use this to build an application on top of `pdfcpu.io`

Comment: @mkl do you have shorter documentation on how to build a PDF reader, to be specific table data?

Comment: *"do you have shorter documentation on how to build a PDF reader"* - shorter in what way? The PDF specification is already shorter than it should be; there are numerous aspects in it which should have been discussed in more detail. A shorter documentation will hardly cover the PDF format, not in an understandable form at least. *"to be specific table data"* - If you mean you "only" want to implement table extraction, simply skip the sections not of interest.

Comment: @KJ ;) I though more about skipping stuff like 3D or movie annotations...

Comment: Thank you for the discussion. I have no idea most of the words  that both @KJ and @mkl used. So, I decided to give up and install `$ sudo apt-get install poppler-utils` on my Dockerfile.

Comment: @kidfrom We did not want to scare you, merely to make clear that PDF is a complicated format, even for seemingly simple tasks like table extraction. Using an existing PDF library or utility usually is a good choice here.